# Change formatting of an element in ChoiceMenu

Tags: hyperref, color, bold

Is there anyway to change color in the `\ChoiceMenu` items such as Item 1, Item 2, etc.? Or even bolding individual choices would work... I tried `\textbf{Item 1}` and `\color{blue}{Item 1}` and they both don't seem to work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
  \ChoiceMenu[print,combo,default=Box 1,name=box1,color=0.862745 0.0784314 0.235294]{}{Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, Item 4, Item 5}
  \quad
  \ChoiceMenu[print,combo,default=Box 2,name=box2, color=0.196078 0.803922 0.196078]{}{Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, Item 4, Item 5}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Where is `\ChoiceMenu` defined?

Comment: I don't think `\ChoiceMenu`, defined by `hyperref`(section 6) really takes parameters in the form of `LaTeX`-code. I only had a quick glanse at the documentation, but it seems to be either Java-code or Acrobat-specific.

Comment: Some knowledge in JavaScript is necessary to access such stuff

Comment: @D.Dal: You'll note that I changed your code snippet into something that is more useful and shows only the relevant content that you want. There's no need for five `\ChoiceMenu`s when two (or even one) will do. Also, you need to include all the relevant packages to reproduce the problem, like [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) in this case. We call that a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Comment: I don't think that the pdf specification contains something that would allow individual formatting of the values of a choice field.

Comment: @Werner sorry, thanks for correcting. Is there anyway at all to get differences (doesn't matter how they are different) in the individual choices of \ChoiceMenu? If not, is there another way in Latex to have a button with some sort of dropdown that can have different individual options?

Comment: If your approach is to provide a limited number of choice options, you could use radio buttons. Of course, adding some form of identifier (like a `*`) next to "special items" in the list is also an option.